# Pass keypress event to a different textbox

Tags: c#, sendkeys

i have a datagridview showing information in some columns, each column has an invisible textbox for searching in it. When user click on one column i get the column index and if the user tips any key I write the key on the textbox and make it visible for a one second. After 1 second I refresh the datagridview applying the text from the textbox as filter and i make the textbox invisible again.

```
private void buscarInformacion(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (indiceBusqueda >= 0)
        {
            listTextBox[indiceBusqueda].Visible = true;
            listTextBox[indiceBusqueda].Focus();
            SendKeys.Send(e.KeyData+"");
            e.Handled = true;
            assistant.TextChanged();
        }

    }
```

But i have one problem with backspace or similar system keys (write "Back" instead of removing one char). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do something like `SendKeys.Send(e.Key == Key.Back ? "{BACK} " : e.KeyData + "");`? Assuming that's where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Thx for the comment, but I have discard this because I would need to make a condition for every special key, I thought that it will exist an easier mode to create a copy of the event but in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is this line:

```
SendKeys.Send(e.KeyData+"");
```

What this is *technically* doing is calling .ToString() on the e.KeyData - which means if the keystroke is a backspace, it's saying

```
[A backspace character].ToString() + "";
```

... aka, it's not sending an actual backstroke - it's sending a text representation of it instead (which you've seen doesn't work.)  The reason it's doing this is because when you add pretty much anything together with a string, it calls the ToString() method to make the things compatible (3 + "a" turns into 3.ToString() + "a" which turns into "3" + "a" which results in "3a".)

Okay, so what are your options?

Option #1 - Don't use SendKeys.  Send the actual Key event to the appropriate GUI control.

Option #2 - Don't use an invisible text box to gather the data and a different element to display it.  When you click the column, have it pop up the text box and let the user type in *that* text box.  No keystroke redirection shenanigans.

Option #3 - Make a child class of the TextBox control, and add your behaviors in there.  Honestly, this is the low-maintenance option, and what you *should* go with (heaven help your successor if you need to add new columns or resize things.)  Have your 'ShortTermTextBox' popup, and auto-close when there aren't any keypresses inside it for more than a second.  Then when you click a column, have it create a *new* ShortTermTextBox on the fly.

Anyway, hopefully that helps out!  Best of luck  :-)

Comment: Option #1 - Don't use SendKeys. Send the actual Key event to the appropriate GUI control. --> how can i make it? This is my first form with c# and im learning so forgive me if the question its too obvious